# finding link element using selenium inside span

Tags: python, selenium, find, element

I am trying to get a csv file but selenium is not able to find the element
i am able to fill the form. website url is "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"
to download the csv i have to click on element with text = Download file in csv format but it's not finding it.
        print(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
        @id="historicalData"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP7Ns.png)/span[2]/a').click())
i have tried using css selector and link text, tag name but getting error not able to locate element.
[link is highlighted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP7Ns.png)

Comment: Please show the selenium code you have written so far.

Comment: symbol = 3MINDIA
    browser.get(url)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dataType"]/option[contains(text(), "Security wise price volume data" )]')\
        . click()
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('reporttitle1').send_keys(symbol)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="series"]/option[contains(text(), "EQ")]').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dateRange"]/option[contains(text(), "3 months")]').click()
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('getdata-button').click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are going to need here is

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), 'Download file in csv format')]').click()
```

An absolute xpath, with a lot of elements in it, is very sensitive to change.

Comment: tried it i am getting error SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(text(), Download file in csv format]' is not a valid XPath expression

Comment: not it's still not working i have corrected the syntax error initially but still Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(), "Download file in csv format")]"} 
please check the url inspect the link.

Comment: Just tested it myself, it worked. Try putting in a 1 second wait before clicking on the download file link.